# How to make a character from 6 bitmaps?

Tags: android, bitmap, character, sprite

I have 6 different pictures that make up a character. The parts are: Right Hand, Left Hand, Head, Eyes, Shirt(body), and Pants(legs). what is the easiest part to make up the character? right now I'm using one method that is to create them in an order and calculate everything, example:

```
       canvas.drawBitmap(handL, pX - handL.getWidth()+ (handR.getWidth()), pY - shirt.getHeight() + handL.getWidth(), null);
       canvas.drawBitmap(pants, pX , pY-handR.getWidth(), null);
       canvas.drawBitmap(shirt, pX, pY - shirt.getHeight(), null);
       canvas.drawBitmap(head, hX, hY, null);
       canvas.drawBitmap(handR, pX + shirt.getWidth() - (2 *handR.getWidth()/3), pY - shirt.getHeight() + handR.getWidth(), null);
       hX = pX - (handR.getWidth()/2) ;
       hY=pY - shirt.getHeight()- head.getHeight() +2;
```

it was hard to calculate everything but after half an hour i figured it out. I want an easier way because I'm going to have to use it many times and I don't want to rewrite it over and over.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice way to generate and update character parts is to work with sprites. You build up an image composed with every parts that your character will need, then you calculate the positions for each of them (pretty easy if all parts are for exemple 50x50). Then, you add the same image for every part, except that you display only the wanted part of it by changing display size and image position.

That way, you will never have to update an image path since all will depend on where you are in your sprites.

(I unforunately don't have worked on android yet, but a new thread have just been opened on how to make sprites in android : [How to make sprites in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430089/how-to-make-sprites-in-android))

Hope this helps

Comment: can you give an example code? i don't understand what you mean by using the sprite. What i want is to draw them so in the future i wont have to change the whole pic for armor. i want to be able to make lots of combinations, that's why im making them in layers.

Comment: I just edited my previous to say that there's a new thread on this question, I personally don't have worked yet with android but I'm sure they have something for this.

What I mean by sprites is an image that contains every possible parts of your character. For exemple, if you have 3 kinds of head, 2 kinds of hands, etc etc, your sprite image will contain everything, something like 18-20 images into one.

On the display, it's cool to deal with because every part is the same image, but in a different portion of it.

Take a look at http://csssprites.com/ for an example of sprite generator.

Comment: Thanks im going to check it tomorrow